# Filling SVG with Wave Animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I have a SVG logo that I want to fill with a wave animation that I made.

At the moment, I was only able to fill a circle made with CSS.

Progress so far: https://codepen.io/luizgununes/pen/rNqKrVx

```
  .water {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform:translate(0,100%);
    background:#FFCA00;
    transition: all .3s;
    
    &_wave {
      width: 200%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      &_front {
        left: 0;
        fill: #FFCA00;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        animation: wave-front .7s infinite linear;
      }
    }
  }
```

There is a way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I've have another example about what I want, but I don't know how to add the wave in this case: https://codepen.io/luizgununes/pen/mdzKjrj

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: What you show is not standard CSS. You must tag this question with whatever it is you are using. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

this is a little tricky, based on your current approach (I think it can be improved in terms of positioning), I can think in a trick like this, not sure if it is what you want, but it is creative enough

If you want something more complicated, I would recommend to generate a html5 video and auto play it with hidden controls (like old google's gmail animation login) or generate somehitng with 2d canvas or full svg (a lot of code and external libraries)

```js
var cnt = document.getElementById("count");
        var water = document.getElementById("water");
        var percent = cnt.innerText;
        var interval;

        /** added code */
        var logo2Container = document.querySelector(".logo2-container");
        var logo2Gradient = document.querySelector(".logo2-gradient");
        var height = 280;
        /** end added code */

        interval = setInterval(function () {
            percent++;
            cnt.innerHTML = percent;
            water.style.transform = 'translate(0' + ',' + (100 - percent) + '%)';

            /** added code */
            logo2Container.style.height = 280 / 100 * percent + 'px';
            logo2Gradient.style.height = 280 / 100 * percent + 'px';
            /** end added code */

            if (percent == 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 60);
```

```css
/** edits */

        .logo2-container {
            overflow: hidden;
            /** height: 280px; */
            width: 280px;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            transition: all .3s;
        }

        .logo2-gradient {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 3;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 201, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 201, 0, 0.8) 20px, rgba(255, 201, 0, 0) 40px);
        }

        .logo2 {
            height: 280px;
            width: 280px;
            position: absolute;
            /** bottom must be in px */
            bottom: -70px;
            z-index: 3;
            right: 10%;
        }

        /** end edits */

        body {
            background: white;
        }

        .box {
            height: 280px;
            width: 280px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background: white;
            border-radius: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .box .logo {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 280px;
            width: 280px;
            top: 25%;
            right: 10%;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .box .percentNum {
            display: none;
        }

        .box .water {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform: translate(0, 100%);
            background: #FFCA00;
            transition: all .3s;
        }

        .box .water_wave {
            width: 200%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 100%;
        }

        .box .water_wave_front {
            left: 0;
            fill: #FFCA00;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
            animation: wave-front .7s infinite linear;
        }

        @keyframes wave-front {
            100% {
                transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            }
        }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        style="display: none;">
        <symbol id="wave">
            <path
                d="M420,20c21.5-0.4,38.8-2.5,51.1-4.5c13.4-2.2,26.5-5.2,27.3-5.4C514,6.5,518,4.7,528.5,2.7c7.1-1.3,17.9-2.8,31.5-2.7c0,0,0,0,0,0v20H420z">
            </path>
            <path
                d="M420,20c-21.5-0.4-38.8-2.5-51.1-4.5c-13.4-2.2-26.5-5.2-27.3-5.4C326,6.5,322,4.7,311.5,2.7C304.3,1.4,293.6-0.1,280,0c0,0,0,0,0,0v20H420z">
            </path>
            <path
                d="M140,20c21.5-0.4,38.8-2.5,51.1-4.5c13.4-2.2,26.5-5.2,27.3-5.4C234,6.5,238,4.7,248.5,2.7c7.1-1.3,17.9-2.8,31.5-2.7c0,0,0,0,0,0v20H140z">
            </path>
            <path
                d="M140,20c-21.5-0.4-38.8-2.5-51.1-4.5c-13.4-2.2-26.5-5.2-27.3-5.4C46,6.5,42,4.7,31.5,2.7C24.3,1.4,13.6-0.1,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l0,20H140z">
            </path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <div class="box">
        <svg class="logo" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            x="0px" y="0px">
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m221.55,126.93l-44.23-11.85c-6.9,2.85-14.2,4.29-21.73,4.29-31.51,0-57.15-25.63-57.15-57.15S124.08,5.07,155.59,5.07s57.14,25.64,57.14,57.15c0,6.62-1.12,13.1-3.35,19.3l12.17,45.41Zm-45.45-26.72l25.58,6.85-7.07-26.39.89-2.19c2.11-5.18,3.18-10.65,3.18-16.26,0-23.77-19.33-43.1-43.1-43.1s-43.1,19.33-43.1,43.1,19.34,43.1,43.1,43.1c6.35,0,12.47-1.35,18.19-4.03l2.32-1.08Z" />
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m133.09,84.62c-6.08-6.08-9.43-14.17-9.43-22.77s3.35-16.68,9.43-22.77c6.08-6.08,14.17-9.43,22.77-9.43s16.68,3.35,22.76,9.43l-7.45,7.45c-4.09-4.09-9.53-6.35-15.32-6.35s-11.23,2.25-15.32,6.35c-4.09,4.09-6.35,9.53-6.35,15.32s2.25,11.23,6.35,15.32l-7.45,7.45Z" />
            <path class="cls-1"
                d="m144.33,72.84c-3.02-3.01-4.68-7.02-4.68-11.29s1.66-8.27,4.68-11.29c3.01-3.02,7.02-4.68,11.29-4.68s8.27,1.66,11.29,4.68l-7.45,7.45c-2.05-2.05-5.62-2.05-7.67,0-1.03,1.02-1.59,2.39-1.59,3.84s.57,2.81,1.59,3.84l-7.45,7.45Z" />
            <style>
                .cls-1 {
                    fill: #e1e4e8;
                }
            </style>
        </svg>
        <div class="percent">
            <div class="percentNum" id="count">0</div>
        </div>
        <div id="water" class="water">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 560 20" class="water_wave water_wave_front">
                <use xlink:href="#wave"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="logo2-container">
            <svg class="logo2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
                <path class="cls-1"
                    d="m221.55,126.93l-44.23-11.85c-6.9,2.85-14.2,4.29-21.73,4.29-31.51,0-57.15-25.63-57.15-57.15S124.08,5.07,155.59,5.07s57.14,25.64,57.14,57.15c0,6.62-1.12,13.1-3.35,19.3l12.17,45.41Zm-45.45-26.72l25.58,6.85-7.07-26.39.89-2.19c2.11-5.18,3.18-10.65,3.18-16.26,0-23.77-19.33-43.1-43.1-43.1s-43.1,19.33-43.1,43.1,19.34,43.1,43.1,43.1c6.35,0,12.47-1.35,18.19-4.03l2.32-1.08Z" />
                <path class="cls-1"
                    d="m133.09,84.62c-6.08-6.08-9.43-14.17-9.43-22.77s3.35-16.68,9.43-22.77c6.08-6.08,14.17-9.43,22.77-9.43s16.68,3.35,22.76,9.43l-7.45,7.45c-4.09-4.09-9.53-6.35-15.32-6.35s-11.23,2.25-15.32,6.35c-4.09,4.09-6.35,9.53-6.35,15.32s2.25,11.23,6.35,15.32l-7.45,7.45Z" />
                <path class="cls-1"
                    d="m144.33,72.84c-3.02-3.01-4.68-7.02-4.68-11.29s1.66-8.27,4.68-11.29c3.01-3.02,7.02-4.68,11.29-4.68s8.27,1.66,11.29,4.68l-7.45,7.45c-2.05-2.05-5.62-2.05-7.67,0-1.03,1.02-1.59,2.39-1.59,3.84s.57,2.81,1.59,3.84l-7.45,7.45Z" />
                <style>
                    .logo2-container .cls-1 {
                        fill: #ffffff;
                    }
                </style>
            </svg>
            <div class="logo2-gradient"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2nd effect demo (original SVG from post needs to be edited to work with clip-paths)

```css
.triangle {
            clip-path: url(#shape);
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-blend-mode: screen;
            background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
            background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
            background-repeat-x: repeat;
            background-position-y: 135px;
            background-size: 200px 500px;
            animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes animate {
            0% {
                background-position-y: 300px;
                background-position-x: 0;
            }
            100% {
                background-position-y: -100px;
                background-position-x: 1200px;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <!--
        SVG as base64 backgound
        <svg viewBox="0 0 500 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <path d="M0.00,49.99 C150.00,150.00 349.20,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #08f;"></path>
        <rect width="500" height="1000" y="100" style="fill:#08f;" />
    </svg>
    -->

    <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <path
                    d="M0.500, 0.945 L0.994, 0.090 L0.006, 0.090 L0.500, 0.945 L0.500, 0.650 L0.262, 0.238 L0.738, 0.237 L0.500, 0.650z">
                </path>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>

    <div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. In fact, I've created that circle to test the wave effect, what I need is the logo being filled by the yellow wave instead the wave covering the logo. But I will look these alternatives.

Comment: I get it, I have edited the answer with a 2nd demo with that, but your svg needs to be edited and you have to generate a waves svg with the forms that you want, but it shows a basic method of how to do it with svg's. From that point you can work to get the job done (it is not so easy, I know), other option is full canvas (maybe it is not so different from svg walking about code?) or a video autoplayed with invisible controls. Good luck!